# How to get key and value from Map in ATG ?

Tags: atg

How to get key and value from Map in ATG ?

```
<dsp:getvalueof var="omap" param="map"/>

<dsp:valueof value="${omap.key}"/>
```

I am not able to see any values, I have multiple key and value in map

```
<dsp:valueof value="${omap}"/>
```

working fine.

Comment: Everything seems correct.  Could you try using `<c:out value="${omap.key}>nothing found</c:out>`?  Have you tried hard-coding your key in?

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes now it is working, just passed that map to forEach droplet and get key and element(value). thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use ServiceMap datatype in your class and in your JSP use code snippet

```
<dsp:droplet name="/atg/dynamo/droplet/ForEach">
<dsp:param name="array" param="empployeemap"/>
<dsp:setvalue param="employee" paramvalue="element" />

<dsp:oparam name="output">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"><dsp:valueof param="employee.empid" /></td>
        <td width="20%"><dsp:valueof param="employee.dob" /></td>
        <td width="70%"> </td>
    </tr>
</dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a Map, you need to use `ForEach` droplet for iterating this Map("omap")

```
<dsp:getvalueof var="omap" param="map"/>

<dsp:droplet name="/atg/dynamo/droplet/ForEach">
<dsp:param name="array" value=${omap}/>
  <dsp:oparam name="output">
    Key:: <dsp:valueof param="key" /> <br />
   Value :: <dsp:valueof param="element" /> <br /> 
  </dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```